# Discord.py How to download the server icon?

Tags: discord.py

I want to make my bot download the server icon, but using that guild.icon I only get a string of numbers and letters and not a URL. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Guild.icon_url) you can see that you can use `guild.icon_url` to get an url to the servers icon. So if you want to get the server icon from the guild a message is from.

You can use `ctx.guild.icon_url` to get the url to the icon:

```
@commands.command()
async def get_server_icon_url(self, ctx):
    icon_url = ctx.guild.icon_url
    await ctx.send(f"The icon url is: {icon_url}")
```

The reason that `guild.icon` does not work as expected. Is that `guild.icon` returns the hash of the icon instead of an url.

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.guild.icon_url` doesn't work, try `ctx.guild.icon.url` instead.

```
@commands.command()
async def get_server_icon_url(self, ctx):
    icon_url = ctx.guild.icon.url
    await ctx.send(f"The icon url is: {icon_url}")
```